# 3 switches and 4 lights

Tags: logical-deduction, combinatorics

The are three switches (1, 2 and 3) and four lights (A, B, C and D). Each switch turns on exactly two lights and no two switches turn on identical lights. You know that

- Lights A, B and C are on when switches 1 and 2 are down.
- Lights A, C and D are on when switches 1 and 3 are down.
- Lights B, C and D are on when switches 2 and 3 are down.

Can you figure out which switch controls which lights? Good luck!

Comment: 3 - A & B, 2 - A & D, 1 - B & D.

Comment: Please post your answer as answer not comment. Also explain how you got it.

Comment: Unmentioned lights are off?  Without that rule, there are 7 solutions instead of 1.

Comment: yes they are off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> 1 is A and C because if 1 is D then 1 and 2 would have D, if one was B then 1 and 3 would have B.

> 2 is B and C because if it was A then 2 and 3 would have A if D then 1 and 2 would have D.

> 3 is C and D because if B then 1 and 3 would have b and if A then 2 and 3 would have A.

Answer (score 0):

C is forever on.

```
-------------------------
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
-------------------------
|  +  |  +  |  *  |     |    3rd lamp is on
-------------------------
|  +  |     |  *  |  +  |    2nd lamp is on
-------------------------
|     |  +  |  *  |  +  |    1st lamp is on
-------------------------
```

So, 3 - A & B, 2 - A & D, 1 - B & D

PS: I don't know how to hide all these things. What I know is >! and that hides only one block of sentence or paragraph.